# "Project with path 'build' could not be found." When import a GitHub project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I tried to import a project from github to AS.

I replaced `build.gradle  gradle and gradle.properties` in the folder with my local file.

But when I import that project,it showed like this :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y3v3.png): [image]

so what should I do? Thanks!